# PrimeFaces Tree scrollable fixed size

Tags: primefaces, tree, scroll

I have a huge tree component in my primefaces application. The tree has hundreds of nodes and I want the tree to have fixed height in my UI with vertical scroll to navigate the nodees.

Can someone help me figure this out?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the `scrollable` and `scrollHeight` attributes? Where is the code you're working with?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes I used both for <p:tree and I didn't get the result.

Comment: See scrollPanel with mode="native": https://stackoverflow.com/q/42621409/1599699

Answer (score 14):

Put that tree in a panel and then apply style to that panel. For example:

```
<p:outputPanel style="width: 100%;height: 100px;overflow: auto;display: block">
       <p:tree value="#{bean.root}">
              <p:treeNode>  
                    <h:outputText value="#{doc}" />
              </p:treeNode>
       </p:tree>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: @user3348246 if you got your answer please click the checkmark next to the answer to accept it

Answer (score 1):

I use `p:scrollPanel`

```
<p:scrollPanel style="height:450px;width:500px;">
    <p:tree ...>
    </p:tree>           
</p:scrollPanel>
```

Comment: Take a look at. This doesn't work.
http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=23508

Comment: I tried `h:form`, `div`, `p:outputPanel`, but only `p:scrollPanel` worked for me (my code differs from code in parent comment only in height and width values). It works both in `mode=default` and `mode=native` well.

Answer (score 0):

p:scrollPanel does not work well.

Use: p:layout

Here an example:

```
            <p:layout style="max-width:800px;min-height:300px;width:800px;height:300px;">
                <p:layoutUnit position="north">
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label,value"
                        style="text-align:left;">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Nombre:" for="nombre" />
                        <p:outputLabel id="nombre"
                            value="#{segPerfilBean.currentObject.segPerNombre}"
                            title="Nombre" />
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:layoutUnit>
                <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                    <h:panelGrid id="catalogContent" style="width: 100%;">
                        <p:tree value="#{segPerfilBean.rootOpciones}" var="doc"
                            disabled="true" readOnly="true" selectionMode="checkbox"
                            selection="#{segPerfilBean.selectedNodes}"
                            style="width:100%;height:100%;">
                            <p:treeNode type="perfil">
                                <h:outputText value="#{doc.segPerNombre}" />
                            </p:treeNode>
                            <p:treeNode type="modulo">
                                <h:outputText value="#{doc.segModNombre}" />
                            </p:treeNode>
                            <p:treeNode type="opcion">
                                <h:outputText value="#{doc.segOpcNombre}" />
                            </p:treeNode>
                        </p:tree>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:layoutUnit>
            </p:layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:tree value="#{bean.root}"
   style="width: 100%;height: 100px;overflow: auto;display: block">
      <p:treeNode>  
          <h:outputText value="#{doc}" />
      </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>`
```

Comment: Please explain how this helps

Comment: When give a fix height in tree will display a scroll automatically.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way to make this work. However, I will admit upfront it was not my dream solution.  But then I have only so much time to play around as this is a bit of a pet project for me:

I created two instances of the table with the same definitions and used fixed header widths.  I then placed each table one after the other in individual divs.  I then style those divs:

```css
#header {
  height: 24px;
}
#body thead {
  display: none;
}
```

and then the I have a sample of simple tables and divs below:

```html
<div id="header">
  <p-treeTable [value]="[]">
    <p-column field="key" header="Key" [style]="{'width':'30%'}">
      <ng-template let-row="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
        {{ row.data.key }}
      </ng-template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="key" header="Key" [style]="{'width':'70%'}">
      <ng-template let-row="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
        {{ row.data.big }}
      </ng-template>
    </p-column>
  </p-treetable>
</div>
<div id="body">
  <p-treeTable [value]="treedata">
    <p-column field="key" header="Key" [style]="{'width':'30%'}">
      <ng-template let-row="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
        {{ row.data.key }}
      </ng-template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="key" header="Key" [style]="{'width':'70%'}">
      <ng-template let-row="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
        {{ row.data.big }}
      </ng-template>
    </p-column>
  </p-treetable>
</div>
```

What I think helped is ensuring I set the width on each column so I could ensure I got the same column width during display.  I also set the treedata to [] or empty for the header so I do not process the data two times.  This is a bit inelegant.  And I would sure have liked to add scrolling directly to the treetable but time is not available.

Also to have the table itself scroll. use something like:

```css
.ui-treetable-tablewrapper {
   overflow-y: scroll;
   height: 290px;
}
```

NOTE:  I have no idea how to get the height so a row is not a bit clipped. As it seems the row height for expanded rows is not identical to that of unexpanded rows.

If you place this in a bootstrap panel with a footer and no padding it looks good, albeit not perfect:

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     ...header...
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="{ padding: '0' }">
     ...Table...
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
      <div class="row">
      ....footer...
    </div>
  <div>
</div>
```